# View not refreshed after AngularJS controller array model modification

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am doing a sample project in order to learn it. I searched the web thoroughly and tried all proposed solutions and all in vain. I still don't know what mistake I did that is causing this issue.

I am trying to build an AngularJS sample application. I want to have a parent layout with its controller (AppLayoutController) in order to handle stuff like logging out while at the same time sharing the navigation bar, etc...

My ui-router configuration is as follows:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('appLayout', {
        templateUrl: 'views/appLayout.html',
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'AppLayoutController',
        controllerAs: 'appLayoutControllerVm'
    })
    .state('roles', {
        url: '/roles',
        templateUrl: 'views/roles.html',
        controller: 'RolesController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        parent: 'appLayout'
    });
```

My controller code is the following:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('RolesController', RolesController);

RolesController.$inject = ['AuthorizationService'];
function RolesController(AuthorizationService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.dataLoading = true;
    //vm.roles = [];

    AuthorizationService.GetRoles().then(function (loadedRoles) {
        vm.roles = loadedRoles;
        vm.dataLoading = false;
    });
}
})();
```

My service code is the following:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .factory('AuthorizationService', AuthorizationService);

AuthorizationService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function AuthorizationService($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

    service.GetRoles = GetRoles;

    return service;

    function GetRoles() {
        // Get the deferred object
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Initiates the AJAX call
    $http.get('/api/roles').success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);

        // Returns the promise - Contains result once request completes
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
})();
```

Finally, my html code is the following:

```
<div>
    Data Loading: {{ vm.dataLoading }}
    <div ng-repeat="role in vm.roles">
        <div>{{role.name}}</div>
        <div>{{role.description}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's happening is the following:

1. I placed a breakpoint in the JS debugger
2. When I refresh the page and before calling the API to retrieve the roles
3. The page is showing up with the dataLoading set to false and no roles displayed
4. When I continue on the breakpoint, the dataLoading passes to true, however the roles remain empty, even thought the API is returning a list containing one role. the ng-repeat is not being refreshed.

What I tried to do to solve it (non-exhaustive :)):

- I tried initializing the vm.roles to []
- I tried replacing "vm.roles = loadedRoles;" by: push.apply, angular.extend or even trying to transform the loadedRoles from JSON to a simple array
- Using the $scope instead of the vm.roles
- Removing the $q

I am out of tricks!

Answer (score 0):

try $scope.$apply

```
AuthorizationService.GetRoles().then(function (loadedRoles) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        vm.roles = loadedRoles;
        vm.dataLoading = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thank your for trying to help. I just tried what you proposed. Unfortunately, it did not work and I got 3 errors of type: "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest" .

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out if someone is facing a similar issue.
The problem was that AngularJS was case sensitive and I did not know that.
After 2 days, I solved the problem by replacing in the html file:

```
    <div>{{role.name}}</div>
    <div>{{role.description}}</div>
```

by

```
    <div>{{role.Name}}</div>
    <div>{{role.Description}}</div>
```

Hope this helps other people.
Cheers!